# Как получить адрес и порт клиента, с которого пришёл HTTP запрос?

Tags: c++, winapi, http, http-server

Делаю HTTP сервер на WinApi. Получаю очередной запрос с помощью `HttpReceiveHttpRequest`, он в качестве параметра принимает указатель на структуру `HTTP_REQUEST`, в которую складываются все данные запроса, однако параметр `CookedUrl` данной структуры содержит адрес, **на** который пришёл запрос, т.е. мой собственный адрес сервера.

Вопрос: как получить адрес **с** которого пришёл HTTP-запрос?

Comment: На кой черт для таких целей использовать WinAPI? Есть же Boost (Asio + Beast).

Comment: @Egorithm Ваш комментарий не относится к сути вопроса и, следовательно, будет оставлен без ответа. С таким же успехом можно было написать "На кой чёрт писать сервер на С" или "На кой чёрт Вам вообще программировать, можно же уборщиком работать пойти".

Comment: Так вы даже язык не указали, кстати.

Comment: @Egorithm уже поправил.

Comment: @V-Mor перефразирую вопрос Egorithm: почему вы используете WinApi? Он не крос платформенный и не переносим, в то же время есть отличная и переносимая альтернатива: boost::beast. У нее и аудитория побольше и документация отличная. На данный момент как минимум 2 человека вам бы уже ответили на ваш вопрос

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch не я решаю, какие технологии использовать. Это требование заказчика. Чтобы было понятнее, добавлю, что работаю на VS 2008 SP1.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, уже приводил этот пример в каком-то из вопросов, но приведу ещё раз, чтобы Вам стало понятно, как примерно выглядят Ваши комментарии. Представьте, что Вы хотите научиться ездить на велосипеде и просите кого-то помочь. А он Вам говорит "зачем тебе велосипед? Мотоцикл же круче. Или автомобиль вот. Учился бы на автомобиле, пошёл бы в автошколу и никаких проблем." Это главная проблема всех форумов: если спрашивают, как сделать одну вещь, не стоит предлагать делать другую.

Comment: @V-Mor извините, но вы передергиваете - ваше сравнение велосипеда и мотоцикла не уместны, не понятно почему вы уточнили про VS 2008 (я же не говорю на каждом углу что пользуюсь vim-ом), к тому же я не говорю: используйте это - я лишь спросил почему? Если уж и брать аналогии с велосипедом, то выглядеть это будет так: вы берете велосипед с овальными колесами и говорите что хотите научиться на нем ездить - я знаю, что с круглыми колесами ездить то легче, поэтому уточняю: а вы точно хотите научится ездить именно на током велосипеде - с круглыми колесами то полегче будет...

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch сравниваю именно велосипед и мотоцикл, потому что они, как и WinApi и Boost оба являются распространёнными средствами (в отличие от овальных колёс) для реализации нужного функционала. Только один из них более старый и, следовательно, менее удобный и функциональный. Про VS написал, чтобы дать понять, что я выбираю инструменты разработки отнюдь не по своему желанию.

Comment: @V-Mor тобишь по-вашему мотоцикл - это новая версия велосипеда? Извините, но единственное, что их объеденяет - это то что у обоих два колеса (но и это не без исключений). Функционал обоих либ практически идентичен, но вот переносимость и документация - выйгрыш бесспорно на стороне boost::beast. Что касается инструмента разработки - сожалею вам: это бредовое требование - какое отношение редактор имеет к конечному продукту? Имеет смысл скорее требования по системе сборке, используемым фрэймворкам и библиотекам, форматированию и прочему.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch повторюсь: это решать не мне. Если у Вас нет предложений по сути вопроса, предлагаю закончить эту бессмысленную дискуссию.

Comment: @V-Mor я только за, но я просто напомню: не я начал рассказывать про велосипеды и мотоциклы - мне было бы достаточно одного предложения про требование заказчика.

Comment: @V-Mor, дык `Address.pRemoteAddress` в том же `HTTP_REQUEST`'е есть, не?

Comment: @V-Mor, не... ответ писать не буду... яхз как это должно будет выглядеть в нормальном виде...

Comment: так вопрос решился?)

Comment: @goldstar_labs - как я понял, участники жаркой дискуссии разошлись по углам ринга, а ообщее мнение свелость к тому, что "что то там должно быть с remote address..." Конкретной функции winapi или примера - никто не написал

Comment: @S.H. Fat-Zer дал ответ на вопрос. `Address.pRemoteAddress` как раз содержит адрес, который мне нужен.